# Can retrofit get json file from assets folder?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Code

```
public interface LocalApi {  

String HOST = "file:///android_asset/";

@GET("{filename}")
Flowable<XXXXBean> getLocalData(@Path("filename") String filename);  

}
```

but I get a **NullPointExpection**, why?

Comment: which point u get null pointer ?

Comment: are you doing this for _production_ or _testing_ purposes? Retrofit turns your **HTTP** API into a Java interface, so it doesn't make sense to use this in a _production_ setting for a **FILE** API.

Answer (score 3):

Internally Retrofit uses OkHttp's `HttpUrl` class to figure out what the actual URL will be. This class is designed to only work for the `http://` and `https://` schemes. This means that it cannot retrieve local files and will either throw an Exception or produce a result you don't expect.